# Traefik - force return 404 for non existing subdomains

Tags: subdomain, reverse-proxy, traefik

## Problem

I am trying to set up Traefik proxy for my docker and non docker services.
All docker services are working fine. I am using two subdomains, admin and app (for example on app.domain.eu/) but now I have problem with non-defined subdomains.

I have set force entrypoint redirect from http to https in the beginning of traefik.toml and this is working fine. When I open non existing website on that subdomain, it returns 404, that's fine.
But when I access non existing subdomain like asdf.domain.eu/, it throws me an error about insecure connection (since I don't have wildcard certificate).

I want to return 404 for all of these subdomains.

## What I have tried?

I tried to set regexp host rule that every subdomain will be redirected to domain.eu/, but it didn't work, showed insecure connection.

I also tried entrypoint override on that frontend so it will go only to http and it didn't work too.

Entrypoint redirection in traefik.toml:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"

  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
```

Redirect in rules.toml

```
[frontends.frontend-apache2-web-subdomains]
  backend = "apache2-web"
  priority = 1
  entrypoints = ["http"] #bypass https for this, not working
  passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.frontend-apache2-web-subdomains.routes.root]
    rule = "HostRegexp: {subdomain:[a-z]+}.domain.eu" # match all subdomains
    [frontends.frontend-apache2-web-subdomains.redirect]
      regex = "^(.*).domain.eu/(.*)$"
      replacement = "https://domain.eu/"
      permanent = true
```

But I am thinking about that better result would be if it just showed 404 on that wrong website instead of redirecting, can I make this instead of redirecting to domain.eu?

### Summary:

Traefik - non existing subdomain - web browser tries to connect but complains about HTTPS. How can traefik send 404 in this case?